# vba Entire Column should copy

Tags: vba, excel

" find " cell value in header will keep changing in raw file, i need " find " cell value ENTIRE column should copy and paste in sheet2

`Sub Macro3()`

```
Cells.Find(What:="FSP Center", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate`
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate`
Columns("A:A").Select 'i want to select entire column 
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro3()
    
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Rows(1).Find(What:="FSP Center", After:=ActiveCell, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        f.EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    End If

End Sub
```

'fixed the misspelling "If"

Comment: Thanks !!! one more thing the cell should search in 1st row. for this any changes ?

Comment: See my edit if you only want to look in the first row